# R combine two columns with opposite values and NA values, into one column, and delete existing

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
structure(list(RFM_Score_Meaning.x = c("Dropped", "Dropped", 
"Dropped", "Dropped", "Dropped", "Dropped", "Dropped", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), RFM_Score_Meaning.y = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Need Encouragement", "Need Encouragement", 
"Need Encouragement", "Need Encouragement", "Need Encouragement", 
"Need Encouragement", "Need Encouragement", "Need Encouragement", 
"Need Encouragement")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tidytable", 
"data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002470fabbfe0>)


RFM_Score_Meaning.x
<chr>
RFM_Score_Meaning.y
<chr>
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
Dropped NA          
NA  Need Encouragement          
NA  Need Encouragement          
NA  Need Encouragement
```

This dataframe is two columns. The places that are NA in the first column have values in the second column, and vice-versa.

How do I get rid of these two columns and instead have one column that that has all the values without any NA values?

Comment: yeah that's the definitely the case after joining. I had a df, then filtered out two categories of things, saved that as df2, did some math on it, then did this operation df3 <- left_join(df, df2, by = 'id'). I think I could have save the variable of interest as a different name to prevent the var.x and var.y thing, but I wasn't sure how to get the end result of the SO post from the join operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  transmute(RFM_Score_Meaning = coalesce(RFM_Score_Meaning.x, RFM_Score_Meaning.y))
```

```
     RFM_Score_Meaning
 1:            Dropped
 2:            Dropped
 3:            Dropped
 4:            Dropped
 5:            Dropped
 6:            Dropped
 7:            Dropped
 8: Need Encouragement
 9: Need Encouragement
10: Need Encouragement
11: Need Encouragement
12: Need Encouragement
13: Need Encouragement
14: Need Encouragement
15: Need Encouragement
16: Need Encouragement
```

Comment: that's great thank you for the help. Is there a way to also make sure I can keep my original columns? The example I shared had just two columns, but the actual data has more. Is that a specific argument I can make also?

Comment: yes. use `mutate` instead of `transmute`. :-)

Comment: Use ```mutate``` instead of ```transmute``` would preserve all columns